# svn pre commit hook inside intellij-idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I use the tortoise client-side pre commit hook to format xml to a canonical, diffable format before commiting to SVN.

I would like to call the same ruby script every time i commit from inside IDEA.
The script needs the list of commited, modified files.

Is there any way to execut a script before commiting from idea?

Ralf

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to reformat code in the `Commit Changes` dialog. If the desired code format is not possible with IntelliJ IDEA built-in code formatting, you'll have to write a plug-in that will integrate into `Commit Changes` dialog and run custom formatting scripts.